# How to set up two-way SSL in rails 4 for custom location?

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails-4, ssl

I am developing rails 4 project with some API,

And I need to configure two-way SSL authentication for these API requests.

I know that two-way SSL means that:

- client and server have certificates
- server check client's sertificate
- client check server's sertificate
- if everything is OK client send a request
- if everything is OK server send a response

But how it can be implement in rails?

And how can it be implemented only for rails API (requests with `/api/..` prefix etc.)?

Or I am not right and it should be implemented on Nginx layer....?

Does any ruby gems for two-way SSL authentication exists?

with easy to understand documentation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem should not be solved on application layer.

Please, find example of `nginx` settings in the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35574958/how-to-set-up-two-way-ssl-in-nginx-for-custom-location).