# How to set up two-way SSL in Nginx for custom location?

Tags: ssl, nginx, configuration, ssl-certificate

I have a rails 4 project with some API.

This project runs with `nginx v.1.6.3` and `https` on production.

Nginx configurations:

```
upstream app {
    # Path to Unicorn SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:/tmp/unicorn.my_domain.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    my_domain.com;
       return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/public.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private.rsa;    

    server_name my_domain.com;

    root /var/www/current;

    location /assets {
        root /var/www/current/public;
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

*Problem*

API requests (`POST /api/some_path/create` etc.) should be protected with two-way SSL.

Only one service will use this API (only 1 client with one certificate)

*Question*

1. Does nginx able to handle `two-way SSL`?
2. `two-way SSL` should be implemented on `nginx`layer, not in web-application logic. am I right?
3. How to set up `nginx` to catch clients which sends requests to `/api/...` url and authenticate them with `two-way SSL`?

I just need a basic example, to understand how it should work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Yes (see the [ssl_client_certificate](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_client_certificate) and [ssl_verify_client](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_verify_client) directives).
2. Depends on your application, but in this case where you only need to verify that the certificate was signed by a certain CA, that's correct.
3. You would need to create a CA and a client certificate signed by said CA and use that CA for verifying the client certificate on the server side.

   Now, what you need to consider is how you will solve the problem that the [ssl_client_certificate](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_client_certificate) and [ssl_verify_client](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_verify_client) directives doesn't support being used in a location block (e.g. they can only be used in a http or server block).

   I would suggest creating an own subdomain for the API (e.g. api.my_domain.com) and access the API from the service with that address.

Example configuration:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/public.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private.rsa;

    ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/client_ca.pem;
    ssl_verify_client on;

    server_name api.my_domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app/api;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This example](https://github.com/ricardona/mtls-nginx-example) is to introduce you to the world of mutual authentication. This tutorial walks you through the steps of configuring two-way security using a NGINX server and connect a website. Therefore, I assume you have some familiarity with the above technologies as well as using Bash and Docker.

```
┌─────────┐       ┌─────────┐       ┌─────────┐       ┌─────────┐
│         │       │         │       │         │       │         │
│ Browser ├──────►│ nginx 1 ├──────►│ nginx 2 ├──────►│ Website │
│         │ HTTPS │         │ mTLS  │         │ HTTPS │         │
└─────────┘       └─────────┘       └─────────┘       └─────────┘
```